# TIPA Centering textipa in tasks list

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, tipa, tasks

I would like to center textipa in task list how can i do that ?

by the way i added `centering` but with no luck

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[style=itemize](5)
\task classic \\ {\Large\centering /\ae//i/ } 
\task desigration \\{\Large \centering \textipa{/e/ /i/ /ei/ } }
\task beast \\ {\Large\centering \textipa{/i:/} } 
\task  blow \\ {\Large\centering  \textipa{/\textschwa u/}}  
\task cordial \\  {\Large \textipa{/\textschwa :/}\textipa{/i\textschwa /} }
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

I tired suggestion of clemens but with no luck heres what i got

[image]

Comment: Does `{\Large\centering /\ae//i/ \par}` work?

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: I guess you need a box...

Answer (score 2):

You need a \par:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}[style=itemize](5)
\task classic \\ {\Large\centering /\ae//i/ \par}
\task desigration \\{\Large \centering \textipa{/e/ /i/ /ei/ }\par }
\task beast  \\ {\Large\centering \textipa{/i:/} \par}
\task  blow \\ {\Large\centering  \textipa{/\textschwa u/}\par}
\task cordial \\  {\Large \textipa{/\textschwa :/}\textipa{/i\textschwa /} \par}
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm, that's what I suggested in a comment and the OP said it wouldn't work. But since you've probably tested this I guess he's wrong...

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer your answer doesn't work for me i already tired the suggestion  of clemens

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? It certainly centers you can see it at the lower /ei/, but perhaps you have a different view on "centering"? Could you make a picture that show the output you want to get?

Comment: but i would like to see /ei/ still in the same line

Comment: Then you shouldn't use such a large font . Or try to hide the width with `\makebox[0pt]{\textipa{/e/ /i/ /ei/ }}`.